# I want to create multiple DOM elements

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to create multiple DOM elements using javascript. The sequence is 'dropdown', '3 textboxes'. When I click on (+) button it all should be placed together. Will someone help me out this???

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     function add_elements(new1)
     {
         var i=1;
        var sel=document.createElement('new1');
        var sel1=document.createElement('new1');
        sel.innerHTML='<select><option value="">--SELECT SIZE--</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="12">12</option><option value="14">14</option><option value="16">16</option></select>';
    var element = document.createElement("input");
    //Assign different attributes to the element.
    element.setAttribute("type", 'text');
    element.setAttribute("name", 'txtRate');
    var foo = document.getElementById("el");
    foo.appendChild(element);            
     }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged the question to jquery,I'm posting this answer

```
$("#add").click(function () {
    var select = $("<select/>");
    select.append($("<option/>", {
        text: "one",
        value: "1"
    }));
    select.append($("<option/>", {
        text: "two",
        value: "2"
    }));
    $("#container").append(select);
    $("#container").append($("<input/>", {
        type: "text"
    }));
    $("#container").append($("<input/>", {
        type: "text"
    }));
    $("#container").append($("<input/>", {
        type: "text"
    }));
});
```

html

```
<div id="container"></div>
<input id="add" type="button" value="addElements"/>
```

you can give any attributes to each element while appending
[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/102/)